# NSDictionary key/value Concept

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

if the key does exist and the following code is executed ll it remove the object and set value for **key** to **nil** or it ll delete the key as well.

```
[myDetails removeObjectForKey:@"Name"];
```

What happens if the key is not present already? Will it generate exception/error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you mean `NSMutableDictionary`, not `NSDictionary`, which is *immutable* and if the key does exist it will remove both the key and value.  If the key does not exist, nothing will happen (no exception will be raised).

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableDictionary/removeObjectForKey%3a):

> **Discussion**
>
> Does nothing if aKey does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

> Does nothing if aKey does not exist.

From [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableDictionary/removeObjectForKey%3a)

Why don't you read the documentation before ask?

Answer (score 1):

It will remove the Objects of that key and Key too.

Here is output of `NSMutableDictionary` before executing `[getDataInSideBySide removeObjectForKey:@"1"];`

```
getDataInSideBySide=={
    1 =     (
        "iProgress23807pm.png",
        "iProgress23822pm.png",
        "iProgress55154pm.png",
        "iProgress65626pm.png",
        "iProgress65639pm.png",
        "iProgress125224pm.png"
    );
    2 =     (
        "iProgress125217pm.png"
    );
```

and after executing `[getDataInSideBySide removeObjectForKey:@"1"]`;

```
getDataInSideBySide=={
    2 =     (
        "iProgress125217pm.png"
    );
}
```

and when I execute `[getDataInSideBySide removeObjectForKey:@"1"];` again, output is same

```
getDataInSideBySide=={
        2 =     (
            "iProgress125217pm.png"
        );
    }
```

It means it does nothing to the `NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: no dear ur very last line is not understandable, i think it did something to NSMutabelDictionary ???

Comment: According to the output I got and also, Apple documentation mentioned in other answers, it does nothing if the key does not exist :)

Comment: yes yes i got it, it modified the dictionary on first call (removal of obj) but on same call again it did nothing, thnks